# How to apply multiple Twig filters to text - SOLVED

Tags: templating, filter

**

After continuing to play around with this I realized that I did not need to add nl2br, adding hacksaw was actually removing the formatting from the rich text field.  I opened a new question [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13702/hacksaw-breaking-rich-text-field)
 if anyone can help or has encountered this issue any help would be appreciated.

**

I have a line

```
 <p>{{ workItem.summary | hacksaw(words='75', append='...') }}</p>
```

I need to add

```
 nl2br
```

to it.  I have tried

```
 <p>{{ workItem.summary | nl2br | hacksaw(words='75', append='...') }}</p>
```

and

```
 <p>{{ nl2br (workItem.summary hacksaw(words='75', append='...')) }}</p>
```

Neither worked.

Can anyone shed some light on the syntax I need to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Do you mean [``nl2br``](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html) (new line to line break?) You have ``nb2lr``.

Comment: Ya that is what I meant

Answer (score 6):

I believe filters are applied in the order they're written. So in your example you're probably applying the new line breaks with `nl2br` and then removing them again with hacksaw.

Try:

```
<p>{{ workItem.summary | hacksaw(words='75', append='...') | nl2br }}</p>
```

Alternatively you could try setting hacksaw to allow line break tags. Something like this (untested):

```
<p>{{ workItem.summary | nl2br | hacksaw(words='75', append='...', allow='<br>') }}</p>
```

I'd go with the first option though.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer, I realized after continuing to play with this that I do not need to add the function I was trying to add.  My issue is comes from adding "hacksaw" to the text is breaking the formatting, I was trying to solve by adding in the nl2br function but I was just misunderstanding the issue.