# Hacksaw plugin breaking rich text field

Tags: plugins, plugin-hacksaw

When I use the [hacksaw](https://github.com/ehousestudio/craft_hacksaw) to truncate the formatting goes away.  If I remove hacksaw it comes back.  So, my question has changed, is there a way for me to truncate the text while keeping the formatting?

The return on the line below is from a rich text field and it will not show formatting unless I remove hacksaw.

```
 {{ workItem.summary | hacksaw(words='75', append='...') }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hacksaw](https://github.com/ehousestudio/craft_hacksaw) has an `allow` parameter where you specify which HTML tags you want it to pass through.

You might want to try something like:

```
{{ workItem.summary | hacksaw(words='75', append='...', allow='<strong><em><br><p>') }}
```

That allows `p`, `br`, `strong`, and `em` tags to pass through untouched. If you need to allow others, just add 'em to the list.